# Derived Column to handled mulitple conditions in CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I've got a `CASE` statement that works, but because I have to do it in SSIS, I am at a loss:

```sql
SELECT [BPCNUM_0], TYPE,

CASE

    WHEN [TYPE]=1 THEN 'Normal'
    WHEN [TYPE]=2 THEN 'Divers'
    WHEN [TYPE]=3 THEN 'Intra-Société'
    WHEN [TYPE]=4 THEN 'Prospect'
END AS TYPE
FROM table
```

As you can see, the case statement evaluates values in one column and renames them depending on what they are.
when I tried this with SSIS, it didn't work

```
[TYPE] == 1 ? "Normal" : [TYPE] == 2 ? "Divers" : [TYPE] == 3 ? "Intra-Société" : [TYPE] == 4 ? "Prospect"
```

I tried also

```
[TYPE] == "1" ? "Normal" : [TYPE] == "2" ? "Divers" : [TYPE] == "3" ? "Intra-Société" : [TYPE] == "4" ? "Prospect"
```

but also it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression needs to add a final **ELSE** statement since it should know the value to assign in case non of the previous conditions is validated:

```
[TYPE] == 1 ? "Normal" : 
[TYPE] == 2 ? "Divers" : 
[TYPE] == 3 ? "Intra-Société" : 
[TYPE] == 4 ? "Prospect" : ""
```

Which is equivalent to the following in SQL:

```sql
SELECT [BPCNUM_0], TYPE,

CASE

    WHEN [TYPE]=1 THEN 'Normal'
    WHEN [TYPE]=2 THEN 'Divers'
    WHEN [TYPE]=3 THEN 'Intra-Société'
    WHEN [TYPE]=4 THEN 'Prospect'
    ELSE ''
END AS TYPE
FROM table
```

If you need to assign a `NULL` value instead of an empty string, you can use the following expression *(Assuming that the derived column type is `DT_WSTR`)*:

```
[TYPE] == 1 ? "Normal" : 
[TYPE] == 2 ? "Divers" : 
[TYPE] == 3 ? "Intra-Société" : 
[TYPE] == 4 ? "Prospect" : NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
```

Comment: the type of the column is tiny int

Comment: @chaneb anything new? Why you have unchecked this answer?

Comment: @chaneb the derived column output type is a `string` make sure you are not mapping it to a numeric destination column.

Comment: @ Hadi 
just one more question plz. My destination column type is tinyint. I'm trying to put a DT_WSTR data into a tinyint data. How am I supposed to fix that? I tried casting it using DT_UI1 but it didn't work!

Comment: @chaneb why you should do that. You should not edit your data since it well designed and stored. You should create another table (example: TypeReference(Id tinyint, Description VARCHAR(50)) and store all the string values that you are using in your CASE statement. Then you should join both tables once you need to retrieve the string values

Comment: For example: `SELECT myTable.*, TypeReference.Description FROM myTable LEFT JOIN TypeReference ON myTable.Type = TypeReference.Id)`

Comment: @chaneb if the purpose of creating the SSIS package is only retrieving those values then no need to create this package.

Comment: @chaneb since your both questions are related. I added those comments to my answer on the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852578/ole-db-destination-invalid-character-value-for-cast-specification

Comment: I’m so thankful for everything you bring to the table. I truly appreciate your hard work