# OLE DB Destination: Invalid character value for cast specification

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

My table source:

| num_facture | TYPE | actif | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2010-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2012-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 2013-01-31 00:00:00.000 |

The Column data types are:

| Column | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| TYPE | tinyint |
| Actif | tinyint |
| date | datetime |

I'm working with SSIS to load my destination table.

So, I want to change `TYPE` for

- `Normal` if 1
- `Divers` if 2
- `Intra-Société` if 3
- `Prospect` if 4

Also, to change `actif` to:

- `no` if 1
- `yes` if 2

Also, get the seniority from the date

So, I created a Derived Column transformation with 3 columns as follows:

**Type Column**

```
TYPE == 1 ? "Normal" : TYPE == 2 ? "Divers" : TYPE == 3 ? "Intra-Société" : TYPE == 4 ? "Prospect" : ""
```

**Actif Column**

```
actif == 1 ? "No" : actif == 2 ? "yes" : ""
```

**Date Column**

```
DATEDIFF("YY",date,GETDATE())
```

All of these transformations didn't work.

> **[OLE DB Destination [288]]** Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  **Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification"**.

> **[OLE DB Destination [288]]** Error: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Derived Column actif] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: **"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."**.

Comment: `"Normal"` is never going to be able to be cast to a `(DT_UI1)`; it's most certainly *not* an integer. The same is true for all of those values in your inline if. Why are you trying to cast them to an `DT_UI1`? What `DT_UI1` value are you expecting a value of `"Normal"`, `"Divers"` and `"No"` to be converted to?

Comment: Depends what solution you are after, @chaneb . There is no solution to trying to convert the `DT_WSTR` value `"Normal"` to a `DT_UI1`, no; it's in no way a 1 byte unsigned integer. hence why I asked why you're trying to convert said values to a `DT_UI1`.

Comment: I removed them but it didn't work 
"Invalid character value for cast specification"

Comment: How did you assume that the `Derived column` is causing the issue while the error shows that it was thrown by the `OLE DB Destination` ?!

Comment: It helps to look into VIEW menu --> Errors list in Visual Studio SSIS, that lists out WARNINGS - resolve them proactively!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main exception is:

> Invalid character value for cast specification.

> The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.

**Check the destination SQL table columns data types and the columns mapping on the destination.**

As the Error description provided in the question shows, it was thrown by the **OLE DB Destination** component. This means that Derived Column Transformations are working fine.

I suggest reading the following article to learn more about SSIS data types, data conversion transformation, implicit and explicit conversion:

- [SSIS Data types: Change from the Advanced Editor vs. Data Conversion Transformations](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-data-types-change-from-the-advanced-editor-vs-data-conversion-transformations/)

Suppose the data type mismatch is caused by the values generated by the Derived Column. In that case, you can try using a casting operator or a *Data Conversion Transformation* to solve the conflict.

Besides, you should be aware that the Derived Column transformation outputs are of type `DT_WTR` or `DT_STR`, so they should be mapped to a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` columns in the destination table.

---

#### Update 1

Based on our discussion on your related question: [Derived Column to handled mulitple conditions in CASE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841176/derived-column-to-handled-mulitple-conditions-in-case-statement). It looks like you are trying to insert a string value within a `tinyint` column as you are trying to replace the type code with the equivalent string value and reinsert it into the SQL table.

**You should not edit your data since it is well designed and stored**. You should create another table *(example: TypeReference(Id tinyint, Description VARCHAR(50))* and store all the string values that you are using in your CASE statement. Then you should join both tables once you need to retrieve the string values.

For example:

```sql
SELECT myTable.*, TypeReference.Description 
FROM myTable LEFT JOIN TypeReference 
     ON myTable.Type = TypeReference.Id
```

Besides, if creating the SSIS package is only for retrieving those values, there is no need to create this package.

Comment: I’m so thankful for everything you bring to the table. I truly appreciate your hard work